# Toggle between two different CSS definitions based on the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this CSS which controls some modal's on the desktop version of the site.

```
#modal, #purchModal, #travModal, #notesModal, #explainModal 
{ position: fixed; z-index: 101; top: 10%; left: 25%; 
   width: 50%; background:#CEECF5; border-radius:15px; 
}
```

If the url contains '/mobile/' I would like to switch the CSS code there to

```
 z-index: 101; top: 5%; left: 5%; width: 95%; 
 background:#CEECF5; border-radius:15px;
```

What exactly would be the best way to do this? I'd imagine I'd be using jQuery or JavaScript here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two different classes for both the styles and `Toggle` them like

```
.Class1 { 
    position: fixed; z-index: 101; top: 10%; left: 25%; 
    width: 50%; background:#CEECF5; border-radius:15px; 
}

.Class2 {
    z-index: 101; top: 5%; left: 5%; width: 95%; 
    background:#CEECF5; border-radius:15px; 
}
```

And toggle them like

```
$('Element you want to change css').toggleClass('Class1' , 'Class2');
```

Or you can use directly like

```
if(document.url.indexOf('mobile')!=-1)
{
    $('Element you want to change css').addClass('Class1');
}
else
{
    $('Element you want to change css').addClass('Class2');
}
```

If you want you can remove the old class and then add the new class in the above approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without using jQuery or JavaScript.
Just write css for different devices

```
//A comman css for class #modal
 #modal {
   position: fixed;
   top: 10%;
   left: 50%;
   z-index: 1050;
   width: 560px;
   margin-left: -280px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
 }

//if screen width is less then 767px
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 #modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

//if screen width is less then 480px
@media (max-width: 480px) {
 #modal {
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  }
}
```

So you can improve your load time without including this unwanted jquery of JS.

Answer (score 1):

First, define your two CSS variations:

```
/* Desktop */
#modal, #purchModal, #travModal, #notesModal, #explainModal {
  position: fixed; z-index: 101; top: 10%; left: 25%; 
  width: 50%; background:#CEECF5; border-radius:15px; 
}

/* Mobile */
body.mobile #modal, body.mobile #purchModal, body.mobile #travModal,
body.mobile #notesModal, body.mobile #explainModal {
  z-index: 101; top: 5%; left: 5%; width: 95%; 
  background:#CEECF5; border-radius:15px;
}
```

Then, have jQuery set the `<body>` class based on the URL on page load:

```
$(function() {
  var isMobile = /\/mobile\/.test(window.location.url);
  $('body').toggleClass('mobile', isMobile);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about having 2 different css files? One for Desktop version and another for Mobile? Change the css file in the page with something like this

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="desktop.css" type="text/css" />');
```